# qt - how to download and save image via http?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to download 1 image and save it. Here is what I have so far:

```
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    QNetworkReply *img = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://placekitten.com/200/300")));

    QImage* img2 = new QImage();
    img2->save(img->readAll(), "omg2.png");
```

But id doesn't work, please help!

EDIT:
That also dont work, i get "oops" in console:

```
 QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
   //connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    QNetworkReply *img = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://placekitten.com/200/300")));

    QImage* img2 = new QImage();
    img2->loadFromData(img->readAll());

    if(img2->isNull())
        std::cout << "oops";

    img2->save("omg2.png");
```

EDIT: 
NOw i get strange error with `vtable`, after `qmake` error still exist:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <iostream>


class omg  : public QObject{

     Q_OBJECT

    public:
        void start(){


            QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
            connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

            manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://placekitten.com/200/300")));
        }


    public slots:
        void replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
        {
           //Check for errors first
           QImage* img2 = new QImage();
           img2->loadFromData(reply->readAll());

           if(img2->isNull())
               std::cout << "oops";

           img2->save("omg2.png");
        }


};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    omg *o = new omg();
    o->start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work specifically?

Comment: I don't get image in any folder (project folder or debug/release)

Comment: You're leaking the memory of omg ... otherwise without seeing vtable error you may need to implement a virtual destructor for omg.

Comment: Thx, but `virtual ~omg(){}` doesnt help, any other suggestion?

Comment: question moved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285661/qt-how-to-download-and-save-image-via-http

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to read data from QNetworkReply even before the Http request is made ,let alone finish.

```
NetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://placekitten.com/200/300")));

...
/*Define  slot and read data from QNetworkreply*/
void finished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
   //Check for errors first
   QImage* img2 = new QImage();
   img2->loadFromData(reply->readAll());

   if(img2->isNull())
       std::cout << "oops";

   img2->save("omg2.png");
}
```

Comment: Could you help me a little more? when I place that whole code in class i get: `Object::connect: No such slot QObject::rfinished(QNetworkReply*) in main.cpp:17`

Comment: You have to create a subclass of QObject first. Then put this code in that class . Read about signals and slots here http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots

Comment: Thx, but i have now one another error with vtable... please look at my last edit!

Comment: Question moved here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285661/qt-how-to-download-and-save-image-via-http thanks in advice!