# QT Downloading File with QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am trying to make the code in this question work.
[qt - how to download and save image via http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285661/qt-how-to-download-and-save-image-via-http)

It creates the files, but no data is written to them.
My best guess is that the connect to the singals and slots is not working.
What am I doing wrong?

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QString getPageImage(QString url = "");
    bool saveToDisk(const QString &filename, QIODevice *data);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_btnDownload_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

qdownload.h

```
#ifndef QDOWNLOADER_H
#define QDOWNLOADER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QFile>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDir>
#include <QDebug>

class QDownloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QDownloader(QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual ~QDownloader();
    void setFile(QString fileURL, QString folderName, QString fileName);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    QNetworkReply *reply;
    QFile *file;

private slots:
    void onDownloadProgress(qint64,qint64);
    void onFinished(QNetworkReply*);
    void onReadyRead();
    void onReplyFinished();
};

#endif // QDOWNLOADER_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
   #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QNetworkAccessManager"
#include "QNetworkReply"
#include "QFile"
#include "QDebug"
#include "QUrl"
#include "QStringList"
#include "qdownloader.h"
#include <QTimer>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->progressBar->setVisible(false);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_btnDownload_clicked()
{
    QString link = ui->txtURL->text();
    int issue = ui->sbIssue->value();
    ui->progressBar->setMaximum(issue);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(0);
    ui->progressBar->setVisible(true);
    for(int j = 1; j <= issue; j++){
        int i = 1;
        while(getPageImage(link + "/" + QString::number(j) + "/" + QString::number(i) + "/").length() > 0){
            QString filename = "http://" + getPageImage(link + "/" + QString::number(j) + "/" + QString::number(i) + "/");
            qDebug() << filename;
            QDownloader qDL;
            qDL.setFile(filename,ui->txtTitle->text() + "_" + QString::number(j),ui->txtTitle->text() + "_" + QString::number(j) + "_" + QString::number(i));
            //qDebug() << getPageImage(link + "/" + QString::number(j) + "/" + QString::number(i) + "/").length();
            i++;
        }
        ui->progressBar->setValue(j);
    }
    ui->progressBar->setVisible(false);
}


QString MainWindow::getPageImage(QString url){
    QString pic = "";
    if(url.length() > 0){
        QNetworkAccessManager manager;
        QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
        QEventLoop event;
        connect(response,SIGNAL(finished()),&event,SLOT(quit()));
        event.exec();
        QString html = response->readAll();

        if(html.length() > 0){
            QStringList str;
            str = html.split("\n");
            //qDebug() << url;

            for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i){
                if(str.at(i).contains("id=\"mainImg\"", Qt::CaseInsensitive)){

                    pic = str.at(i);
                    pic = pic.remove(QRegExp("<img[^>]*src=['|\"]",  Qt::CaseInsensitive));
                    pic = pic.remove(QString::fromStdString("//"), Qt::CaseInsensitive);
                    pic = pic.remove('"');
                    pic = pic.remove("'");
                    pic = pic.remove('<');
                    pic = pic.remove('>');
                    pic = pic.remove(';');
                    pic = pic.left(pic.length()-1);
                    //qDebug() << str.at(i);
                    //qDebug() << pic;
                }
            }
        }else{
            pic = "";
        }
        //qDebug() << "Lines: " << str.size();

    }else{
        pic = "";
    }
    return pic;
}
```

qdownload.cpp

```
#include "qdownloader.h"

QDownloader::QDownloader(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
}

QDownloader::~QDownloader()
{
    manager->deleteLater();
}

void QDownloader::setFile(QString fileURL, QString folderName, QString fileName)
{

    QDir dir;
    if(dir.exists(folderName)){
        //qDebug() << "Existis: " + folderName;
    }else{
        dir.mkdir(folderName);
        //() << "Created: " + folderName;
    }

    QString filePath = fileURL;
    QStringList filePathList = filePath.split('/');
    QString fileExt = filePathList.at(filePathList.count() - 1);
    fileExt = "jpg";
    QString saveFilePath;
    saveFilePath = QString(folderName + "/" + fileName + "." + fileExt );



    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl(fileURL));
    reply = manager->get(request);



    file = new QFile;
    file->setFileName(saveFilePath);


    connect(reply,SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)),this,SLOT(onDownloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));
    connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(onFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    connect(reply,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(onReadyRead()));
    connect(reply,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(onReplyFinished()));
}

void QDownloader::onDownloadProgress(qint64 bytesRead,qint64 bytesTotal)
{
    qDebug(QString::number(bytesRead).toLatin1() +" - "+ QString::number(bytesTotal).toLatin1());
}

void QDownloader::onFinished(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
    switch(reply->error())
    {
        case QNetworkReply::NoError:
        {
            qDebug("file is downloaded successfully.");
        }break;
        default:{
            qDebug(reply->errorString().toLatin1());
        };
    }

    if(file->isOpen())
    {
        file->close();
        file->deleteLater();
    }
}

void QDownloader::onReadyRead()
{
    qDebug() << "Ready";
    file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    file->write(reply->readAll());
}

void QDownloader::onReplyFinished()
{
    if(file->isOpen())
    {
        file->close();
        file->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

Comment: @lpapp, Please double check this. I don't think that would answer this question.

Comment: @mhcuervo: I reopened this for your pleasure, but it was border line in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prepared a very basic example you can use as reference.

In some place in "my" downloader I launch the request:

```
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(org);
_reply = _manager->get(request); // Manager is my QNetworkAccessManager
connect(_reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
            this, SLOT(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
connect(_reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)),
            this, SLOT(updateProgress(qint64, qint64)));
connect(_reply, SIGNAL(finished()),
            this, SLOT(finished()));
```

As you can see all you need to do is to `get()` and properly use the signals of the `QNetworkReply`.
Following "my" slots:

```
void MyDownloader::error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError err)
{
    // Manage error here.
    _reply->deleteLater();
}

void MyDownloader::updateProgress(qint64 read, qint64 total)
{
    // This is where you can use the progress info for, lets say, update a progress bar:
    // progressBar->setMaximum(total);
    // progressBar->setValue(read);
}

void MyDownloader::finished()
{
    // Save the image here
    QByteArray b = _reply->readAll();
    QFile file(des); // "des" is the file path to the destination file
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QDataStream out(&file);
    out << b;
    _reply->deleteLater();
    // done
}
```

Notice that you can write to the file in `updateProgress()` instead of writing the whole file at once when the reply is finished.

---

For writing on `updateProgress()`, open and/or create the `QFile` at `get` time. Then use reply's `readAll` on every update and write the read data to the file then close the file when `finished`.

```
// ...
    _file = new QFile(des);
    _reply = _manager->get(request);
/// ...

void MyDownloader::updateProgress(qint64 read, qint64 total)
{
    QByteArray b = _reply->readAll();
    QDataStream out(_file);
    out << b;
}

void MyDownloader::finished()
{
    // Done
    _reply->deleteLater();
    _file->close();
    // probably delete the file object too
}
```

Comment: How would I go about writing the file in the updateProgress() function?

Comment: There is already a reply = manager->get(request) under QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl(fileURL));
    reply = manager->get(request);

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code to write during the download progress. However the problem appears to be with the signals and slots. For some reason they are not firing. I have a qDebug in each slot and none of them appear when the program runs.

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Qt Creator 3.2.1 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.3.2 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)

Built on Sep 14 2014 at 04:14:50

From revision 602746950b

Copyright 2008-2014 Digia Plc. All rights reserved.

The program is provided AS IS with NO WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, INCLUDING THE WARRANTY OF DESIGN, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Hummm... What I see in your code is that `qDL` become out of scope immediately after calling setFile which result in object destruction. Try forcing `setFile` to wait for reply finished before returning, add this at the end of your `setFile`: QEventLoop eventLoop; connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit())); eventLoop.exec();

Comment: Voted down because the whole download is stored in memory before written out into file. This could be fixed by streaming the data directly into the file (My 4GB download wouldn't fit into memory)