# PyQt6: How can I "handle" a QIODevice::read (QNetworkReplyHttpImpl): device not open error?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt6

I have a downloader program and the user has the option to manually pause/cancel the download. What both the pause and cancel functions have in common is `reply.abort()`, where `reply` is a `QNetworkReply` instance. However, even after `abort` is called, my `downloadProgress` slots still attempt to read from `reply` one last time, probably due to some asynchronicity between the two. When the read is attempted, and since `reply` is closed, I get `QIODevice::read (QNetworkReplyHttpImpl): device not open` output in the console. How do I handle this so as to not get any output in the console? Or, better yet, how can I change my code to prevent that final `reply.read()` call?
Code for pause:

```py
    def pause(self):
        self._network_access_manager.reply.abort()
        self._network_access_manager.reply.disconnect()
```

Code for cancel:

```py
    def cancel(self):
      self._network_access_manager.reply.abort()
```

`downloadProgress` slot:

```py
    def _download_progress_slot(
        self,
        current_data: qtc.QByteArray,
        total_data: qtc.QByteArray
    ):
        data = None
        if 0 <= total_data < 1000:
            data = self._network_access_manager.reply.read(current_data)
            if "text/html" == magic.from_buffer(data, mime=True):
                return print("some kind of error")
        self._write_to_disk(data, current_data)
```

Finally, function to write the data to disk:

```py
    def _write_to_disk(self, data: qtc.QByteArray, current_data: qtc.QByteArray):
        if data is None:
            data = self._network_access_manager.reply.read(current_data)
        
        if data is None:
            # Apparently, trying to read from an expended IODevice returns
            # `None`, and not `-1` or `0` as documented here:
            # https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html#read
            return

        if self._current_working_local_file.write(data) == -1:
            print(
                "FILE WRITE ERROR\n",
                self._current_working_local_file.errorString()
            )
```

Or do I just add `if reply.isOpen()` checks before each `read`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Can't you just check `reply.isFinished()` or `reply.isRunning()` before attempting the next read? Then again, attempting to read more data inside a slot connected to the `downloadProgress` signal (if that's what you're doing - it's not clear from your question) seems like a very bad idea. You should be using [readyRead](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) instead.

Comment: > `reply.isRunning()` < I... didn't think of that.  

@ekhumoro, the slot for `downloadProgress` is `_download_progress_slot`, and it calls to `_write_to_disk`, which writes the data to disk. And yes, I'm reading data from a slot connected to `downloadProgress`, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26394438/14807690. Re-reading the documentation for `downloadProgress`, I do see that `bytesReceived` might be different from total bytes read with `read`, would that be the reason why `readyRead` is better?

Comment: @オパラ To me, it makes more sense to handle `readyRead` first (i.e. by reading the data), and only then handle `downloadProgress` (i.e. by updating the progress-bar). In Qt's implementation, `readyRead` is always emitted *before* `downloadProgress` (which may sometimes be emitted after a short timer delay). I don't know for certain whether doing things the way I suggested above will fix your issue, but it seems worth trying.

Comment: @ekhumoro, adding a check for `isRunning()` before reading from `reply` did kind of fix the issue, but it looks like the last few bytes could not be read because by then `isRunning` returns `False` (I'm guessing the reply is considered "finished" when the last bytes is received). I added a `readyRead` slot to write data (`downloadProgress` now only updates a progress bar) and so far I have yet to run into the "device not open" error! Looks like that's what I needed, thank you.